# Test tree disappears from Test Explorer window, once I run them (VS2022)

Tags: testing, visual-studio-2022, test-explorer

I have this weird behaviour in VS 2022, that once the tests are run in the Test Explorer window, the whole test tree disappears. It works fine for all my coworkers, but not on my machine. The tests are still there somewhere, all counted for, but they refuse to show again in the test tree inside the Test Explorer.

Any ideas what is going wrong on my machine?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

- close the solution
- delete hidden ".vs" directory in the solution folder
- reopen the solution.
- rebuild the solution

Deleting the .vs directory solved this (and some other) problem for me. It's like a "clean reboot" of a Visual Studio solution.

Answer (score 0):

After I reinstalled the packages needed for testing, the test tree apears again, but the tests refuse to run again.